Hide user folders in Windows explorer
They are back! After a recent (June/2024) update these undesired links to folders are back. I have tried all methods of removing them to no avail. And now there's a link to Gallery on the Drives panel as well.

Here's what I have tried:
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}]
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}\PropertyBag]
"ThisPCPolicy"="Hide"

Where B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641 is replaced by all known CLSIDs.
Please help me get rid of this clutter.

On Desktop or in Explorer??

@DrMoishePippik On Explorer under desktop

Two different things. If it's Explorer, then change the title. This might be a useful question and answer, if explained properly.

did so @DrMoishePippik thanks!

Great! Useful Registry fixes.


I needed to add "HiddenByDefault"=dword:1 to keys:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\[CLSID]

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\[CLSID]


The full .reg:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{088e3905-0323-4b02-9826-5d99428e115f}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCLocalDownloadsRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCMyMusicRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{24ad3ad4-a569-4530-98e1-ab02f9417aa8}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCLocalPicturesRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCDownloadsRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCMyPicturesRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{3dfdf296-dbec-4fb4-81d1-6a3438bcf4de}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCLocalMusicRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{d3162b92-9365-467a-956b-92703aca08af}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCLocalDocumentsRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCDocumentsRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{f86fa3ab-70d2-4fc7-9c99-fcbf05467f3a}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCLocalVideosRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCMyVideosRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCDesktopRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{088e3905-0323-4b02-9826-5d99428e115f}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCLocalDownloadsRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCMyMusicRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{24ad3ad4-a569-4530-98e1-ab02f9417aa8}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCLocalPicturesRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCDownloadsRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCMyPicturesRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{3dfdf296-dbec-4fb4-81d1-6a3438bcf4de}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCLocalMusicRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{d3162b92-9365-467a-956b-92703aca08af}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCLocalDocumentsRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCDocumentsRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{f86fa3ab-70d2-4fc7-9c99-fcbf05467f3a}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCLocalVideosRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCMyVideosRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}]
@="CLSID_ThisPCDesktopRegFolder"
"HideIfEnabled"=dword:022ab9b9
"HiddenByDefault"=dword:1

